# List of parameters in JMH benchmark test

Tags: java, performance, testing, benchmarking, jmh

I am writing performance tests for an HTTP server using my custom Java library that is sending REST requests to the server. At the beginning, I am performing data preparation stage in order to have a list of objects that I want to send in requests to my server.

Now, the problem is, that I can test a list of parameters that can be injected into the benchmark function using `@Param` annotation:

```
@Param({"param1", "param2", ...})
```

The problem is, I would like to achieve the same having Java List of parameters and to avoid having to iterate over them. Could you please give me any advice how I can do it?

Comment: If you look at the code at the bottom of [the Params example](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/3769055ad883/jmh-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/samples/JMHSample_27_Params.java) there is a way to programmatically set the parameters (line 97).

Comment: Doesn't change anything, you cannot use List there. The only thing you can do is to have hardcoded parameters.

Comment: Create a `String[]` with the name of the argument first and your list of values next.

Comment: Okay, that would do the trick. And how about other types of params apart from String?

Answer (score 1):

I used a workaround using `@Setup(Level.Trial)` with a `switch` statement inside that initialized parameters as needed.

If you want an example: https://github.com/Imaskar/lettuce-threads/blob/master/src/main/java/fiddle/lettucethreadsbenchmark/LettuceThreads.java

Comment: Sorry, but this is something completely different than I asked. What I want to achieve is having a list of objects (of different than String type) as parameters for benchmark functions. What you propose is to use benchmark parameters to set up something.

Comment: @Konrad to set up objects you want. For example, you want a list of DB connections as parameters. You pass a list of strings "conn1","conn2", "conn3" and construct your objects accordingly.

Comment: You said "At the beginning, I am performing data preparation stage in order to have a list of objects that I want to send in requests to my server.". Well, move your "beginning" to a metohod with @Setup(Level.Trial)

Comment: @Konrad if you want to pass a list of parameters at runtime - my  suggestion not to do this. You may spoil the test. JMH should fork VM, but it won't be as clean as it should be. If you insist, use the same trick I described, but deserialise your objects from string parameters (as json or base64).